# SpotBugs Maven Plugin exclude a directory

Tags: java, maven, spotbugs

I use [SpotBugs Maven Plugin](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/index.html) for a static analysis and I would like to exclude a directory from the inspection. Looking at the `spotbugs:check` [goal documentation](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html), it seems that it is not possible to configure the plugin is such a way. I also checked documentation for a SpotBugs [filter file](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html).

In Apache Maven PMD Plugin this can be done by using [excludeRoots](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/cpd-mojo.html#excludeRoots) parameter:

```xml
<excludeRoots>
  <excludeRoot>target</excludeRoot>
</excludeRoots>
```

Is it possible to exclude a directory from SpotBugs inspection?

Comment: It looks like SpotBugs approaches the issue from the opposite direction. You don't tell it what to ignore, you tell it what to look at: https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html#Specifying_which_classes_to_analyze

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible to exclude a directory from inspection with SpotBugs, though the approach is different to the one you described for PMD. It is a two step process:

1. First [create an XML filter file](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html) specifying the criteria for the directory(s) to be excluded.
2. Then, in **pom.xml** refer to that that file using the optional `<excludeFilterFile>` setting. Unfortunately, [the documentation for that setting](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html#excludeFilterFile) is very brief.

As a simple example:

1. Create a filter file named **ignore.xml** containing the following which refers to a directory named **mydir**:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <FindBugsFilter>
        <Match>
            <Source name="~mydir\..*"/>
        </Match>
    </FindBugsFilter>
   ```

   The documentation for [the `<Source>` tag is here](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html#source). See the section on [Java element name matching](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html#java-element-name-matching) for details on how to specify the **name** of the `<Source>`.
2. Then in **pom.xml**, in the specification for **spotbugs-maven-plugin**, include an `<excludeFilterFile>` tag so that **mydir** is ignored by SpotBugs:

   ```
    <configuration>
      <excludeFilterFile>ignore.xml</excludeFilterFile>
    </configuration>
   ```

Notes:

- There is also an `<includeFilterFile>` tag. See the section titled **Specifying which bug filters to run** in [the usage documentation](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html).
- As well as `Source`, SpotBugs provides several other ways to specify what code is to be included or excluded from checking. See the filter file documentation for the `Package`, `Class`, `Method`, `Local`, `Field` and `Type` tags.
- Place your `<excludeFilterFile>` in the root of your project.

Comment: I tried the solution and it doesn't work. According to this SpotBugs [ticket](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/694) `SourceFilter` does not work with the full file path.

Comment: @Boris Try `Package` instead of `Source`. It works.

Comment: @sgnsajgon I had mentioned `Package` in my answer, but how does that help the OP? Their question is asking how to exclude a specific directory, not a package.

Comment: @Boris It looks like the implementation of open issue [Add management for source filter using full source path (if available). #903](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/pull/903) may be needed to resolve this.

Comment: @skomisa `Application class loader` in JVM (the default one) searches for classes from given package in the corresponding directory structure. i.e class `com.example.app.Class` typically (in practice almost always) is placed in `com/example/app` directory. And vice versa, classes located in `com/example/app` directory typically have `com.example.app` package. So, effectively, excluding a package is usually the same as excluding directory. Of course, there are rare cases when we write or use custom ClassLoaders, but as far as I can see, most JVM applications use default class loading mechanism.

Comment: where would you place that ignore.xml?

Comment: @DanDan and others, I just placed the include/exclude.xml files in the root of the Eclipse project, picked them up fine.

Comment: @JGlass Thanks for that feedback - I just updated my answer accordingly.