# Exclude Paths/Folders with Spotbug

Tags: spotbugs

I would like to exclude a specific Folder from a Spotbug scan. I tried several solutions but none of them worked for me. Firstly I tried to write into .gitlab-ci.yml which Paths to exclude but I had no luck with that.

Secondly I created an XML File in which I specify the Folder to be excluded. And then added the XML to the SpotBug Configuration in pom.xml but that also didn't work.

Somebody got any alternate suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SpotBugs Maven Plugin exclude a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336795/spotbugs-maven-plugin-exclude-a-directory)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but it still didn't work.